# Got ModuleNotFoundError for mysql while connecting mysql from JupyterHub

Tags: mysql, jupyterhub

I got this error when using MySQL instead of SQLite for JupyterHub Session and Token store.

```
[E 2018-06-27 06:04:36.542 JupyterHub app:1623]
jupyterhub4cc    |     Traceback (most recent call last):
jupyterhub4cc    |       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1620, in launch_instance_async
jupyterhub4cc    |         yield self.initialize(argv)
jupyterhub4cc    |       File "/usr/lib/python3.6/types.py", line 204, in __next__
jupyterhub4cc    |         return next(self.__wrapped)
jupyterhub4cc    |       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1373, in initialize
jupyterhub4cc    |         self.init_db()
jupyterhub4cc    |       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 895, in init_db
jupyterhub4cc    |         **self.db_kwargs
jupyterhub4cc    |       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterhub/orm.py", line 526, in new_session_factory
jupyterhub4cc    |         engine = create_engine(url, **kwargs)
jupyterhub4cc    |       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 424, in create_engine
jupyterhub4cc    |         return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
jupyterhub4cc    |       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 81, in create
jupyterhub4cc    |         dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
jupyterhub4cc    |       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqlconnector.py", line 107, in dbapi
jupyterhub4cc    |         from mysql import connector
jupyterhub4cc    |     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have used these three library inside JupyterHub container to connect with MySQL.

- MySQL-python
- mysql-connector-python
- pymysql

And the config used is :

```
c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}/{}{}'.format("test","test","localhost","test","")
```

P.S. I have installed MySQL server locally and created a database **'test'** with username **'test'** and password **'test'**.